# kivy widget with dynamic type

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I want to create a custom widget, MyWidget, which is composed of a *header* and a *body*.

Sometimes, the *header* would be a Label and the *body* a box layout, i.e.:

```
<MyWidget@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        id: header
        text: "Title" 
    BoxLayout:
        id: body
```

But at times I want to group several of these in a TabbedPanel, in which case, MyWidget should behave as:

```
<MyWidget@TabbedPanelItem>:
    text: "Title" 
    BoxLayout:
        id: body
```

That is, MyWidget should be a different thing depending on who is its parent (a Tabbedpanel or anything else), which can be detected with MyWidget.on_parent

I KNOW the standard way to do it is to define two different widgets, MyWidget_Tabbed  and MyWidget_individual, of types TabbedpanelItem and BoxLayout respectively,  but conceptually these two are really the same, just that they are either grouped or ungrouped

How to achieve this?

I'm thinking about having 3 classes: MyWidgetGrouped(TabbedPanelItem), MyWidgetUngrouped(BoxLayout) and MyWidget. 
Only MyWidget will be used in KV. Then, in mywidget.on_parent, I will change mywidget.__class__ to either MyWidgetGrouped or MyWidgetUngrouped (and perhaps I will also have to call __init__ and set __dict__, and other things)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just because 2 objects look the same it doesn't mean they are the same. The interface (contract) for `BoxLayout` and `TabbedPanelItem` are different. Just because they may end up looking similar doesn't make them the same. You **should** use 2 different classes for this as they are **different**.

Now to your question:

Python support multiple inheritance so you can inherit both `BoxLayout` and `TabbedPanelItem`.

I don't know about the inner working of kivy regarding widgets, this may not even work.

But you won't be able to load 2 different layouts from .kv files in the manner you described. You will need to use something like [`Builder.load_string`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.load_string) or [`Builder.load_file`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.load_file) to achieve this.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I tried with multiple inheritance but couldn't make it work. I edited the question, have a look